# Completion handlers in Swift: AVMIDIPlayer

Tags: swift

I'm using AVMIDIPlayer in macOS. The [.play](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avmidiplayer/1388390-play) function takes a completion handler, `AVMIDIPlayerCompletionHandler`, which is a typealias for `Void`.

My code is:

```
   var viewMIDIPlayer: AVMIDIPlayer?

 @IBAction func backToStart(_ sender: Any) {
        if viewMIDIPlayer != nil {
        viewMIDIPlayer!.stop()
        viewMIDIPlayer!.currentPosition = TimeInterval(0)
        playButton.state=NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 1)
        viewMIDIPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        viewMIDIPlayer!.play(self.completed())
            }
        }
        
        func completed() -> AVMIDIPlayerCompletionHandler {
             if self.viewMIDIPlayer!.currentPosition == self.viewMIDIPlayer!.duration {
                 self.playButton.state=NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 0)
                 return
             }
}
```

What I get is an error that the function in .play is unused, and an error in the function itself "Non-void function should return a value".

[image]

If I try `return Void` or `return nil`, or `return 0`, I get type errors. Also this:

[image]

I've also tried something like:

```
viewMIDIPlayer!.play(self.completed?: (AVMIDIPlayerCompletionHandler) -> ())
```

but that just makes matters worse.

I dare say this is something super obvious like more punctuation, but I've got no idea. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove `-> AVMIDIPlayerCompletionHandler` from the function signature so it is just `func completed() { ... }`

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'AVMIDIPlayerCompletionHandler?' (aka 'Optional<() -> ()>')

Comment: I think you need to include more in your question. Please update it so that it is is a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it currently stands it is very hard to debug with out reproducible example. Also `AVMIDIPlayerCompletionHandler` is not a typealias for `Void` it is a typealias for a function that returns `Void`. That is what `() -> Void` means

Comment: @Andrew Don't worry, someone's figured out and explained the function type issue.  Still don't know why Xcode complains that a function which returns void is 'unused', though.

Comment: Try removing the `()` from the end of `self.completed()`

Comment: No, I get the same error as my first comment, in addition to the existing one.

Comment: Ah: it was just a 'lingering' error that went away when I tried building! Fixed! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the completion handler type alias is for a value of type `() -> Void`
That means you have to pass it a function that takes no arguments and returns no value.

It's basically saying you give me a function and I'll call you back when I am done.

Now let's look at your types:

```
viewMIDIPlayer!.play(self.completed())
```

What is the type of the expression "self.completed()"

```
func completed() -> AVMIDIPlayerCompletionHandler {
```

Which is another way of saying

```
func completed() -> () -> Void {
```

i.e. completed is a function that when you call it will return **a function that takes no arguments and returns a void**.

A better name for such a function would be "makeCompletionHandler"

And you might write it like:

```
func makeCompletionHandler() -> () -> Void {
    // I am not returning void, I am returning a function (note the braces here):
    return {
        print("Completion handler was called!")
    }
}
```

But there's absolutely no reason to have this kind of higher-order function.  And you didn't write it like that, you wrote a function that returns void as if *it was the completion handler*, and not a function that returns a completion handler.

You could just write the completion handler inline, like:

```
viewMIDIPlayer!.play {
     if self.viewMIDIPlayer!.currentPosition == self.viewMIDIPlayer!.duration {
         self.playButton.state=NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 0)
}
```